# How to make script to convert lower case characters into upper and vice versa

Tags: automator

Need to create 2 scripts in automator.

1. Select text in any application (textedit, pages etc.) and change all letters from lower case to upper.
2. Same, as above, but from upper case, to lower.

Scripts should work not only with English, but with other languages as well. Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for a lot of apps [not all, but certainly all Apple apps] from

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can convert a text file's content to lowercase or uppercase using the dd command in Terminal.

Convert to lowercase:

`$ dd if=input.txt of=output.txt conv=lcase`

or uppercase:

`$ dd if=input.txt of=output.txt conv=ucase`

Tip: If you're working from the desktop then it may be easier to cd into the directory, rather than copying the file path or dragging and dropping the file into the Terminal window:

`$ cd ~/Desktop`

Comment: Conversions with `dd` only work for a-z/A-Z, not for characters used in other languages than english.

Comment: The question stipulates "select text in any application" but this answer is to "convert a text file's content"

Comment: @ian.pvd this question is 4 years old but anyway... reading the question now, I may have interpreted it as "convert a select text file or document" as opposed to "convert the **selected** text".